# How to run a jar file in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I tried to run a jar file by going to Run configurations and then creating a new Java App, but Eclipse wants me to give it a main class and reference to the project. Can't I just give Eclipse a jar file?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could run the JAR with an "External Tool" launch configuration, found at Run > External Tools > External tools Configurations.

Comment: :D thanks! I found it under Run > External Tools > External tools Configurations and then selected new Program.

Comment: I also try this but it is giving me this issues Exception occurred executing command line.
Cannot run program "D:\CapsON.jar" (in directory "D:\"): CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Comment: @SanjayJain I got a similar error and found GermanK's answer helpful.

Answer (score 58):

You cannot directly execute a jar file. Instead, you need to run it using the `java -jar` command. In order to do that you:

1. Go to Run > External Tools > External tools Configurations
2. Create an item under "Program"
3. Fill in:

   Location: `/usr/bin/java` (or the route to your java executable, in Linux
   you can find this by running `which java` on a terminal, in Windows you can use `where java` in command prompt)

   Working directory: The working directory for your jar program (usually its location)

   Arguments: `-jar [path to your jar]`

Comment: On windows you can use `where java` instead of `which java`.  If you want a JDK and not a JRE you need to look in the returned directories for 'bin/javac/`

Answer (score 5):

Run -> External Tools -> External Tools Configuration.

Program -> New

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Is the jar file you provided have "public static void main(String [] arg)" method ? In order for java to run your and application, a main class with a "public static void main(String [] arg)" method must exist. So that jvm will understand the starting execution point of your jar.

Answer (score 2):

Just create a Java application and start it with the jar flag:

[image]

You can use eclipse variables such as workspace_loc or git_work_tree to point to your jar-file.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following command line

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_24\bin\javaw.exe
```

with the following arguments (one per line)

```
-cp C:\dev\tcpmon-1.0-bin\build\tcpmon-1.0.jar 
org.apache.ws.commons.tcpmon.TCPMon
```

Answer (score -2):

Try running 'java -jar yourprogramname' in a console.