# How should I configure the runtime using jar and config file and run the app in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, log4j, config.json

https://www.dropbox.com/s/g1r4fhxuz5odfaa/tmm.zip?dl=0

For running the app How can I use this command line:

java -jar TMM_x.y.z.jar -c <--path to configuration file-->

Comment: Usually `java -jar TMM_x.y.z.jar` should be enough to run your jar file.

Comment: If you want to run the JAR from within Eclipse IDE I think the easier is to use a dedicated Run Configuration (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52207796/10226142)). There are also plug-ins to embed a terminal within the IDE, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21579383/10226142).

Comment: @Lutzi I had to create a configuration file and run the following command in the maven web project.java -jar TMM_x.y.z.jar -c <--path to configuration file-->